# Large gap between slab and siding of house

Tags: foundation, exterior, siding, sealing

It seems like one side of my house is protruding from the concrete base. This is a 2 yr old house with the gap leading into my kitchen. I eventually noticed after I started seeing some pillbugs in the area every time we had a hard rain.

So my questions are, is this a serious issue for concern? Is this common? And how do I even go about fixing this? Thanks

Pics: https://imgur.com/a/jsX05pU

Answer (score 0):

If the floor above is solid and not springy, then the house foundations are probably okay.  It appear that the lining is past the concrete.  In some jurisdictions, you need a gap there for the water to drain out, in case it gets in.

The only issue is that large vermin could get into the cavities.  For this purpose, around here, we use `Vermin Strips`.  They are slotted channels to stop large vermin from getting in, while allowing water to drain out.